# Web App using neural networks

Tags: php, neural-network, web-frameworks, scalable

I have to build a small web app that uses a classification neural network(such as LVQ) with supervised learning it is not a very complex app but it has to be scalable. I know only PHP and while browsing I came across certain Neural Network managers or classes for PHP (such as Tremani Neural Mesh etc.).I would like suggestions on which platforms I shall use and the libraries, classes for using neural networks in the same so as to make it scalable enough? I am open to learning a new platform too.

Comment: How much do you expect your "small" web app to scale?

Comment: By small I meant it is not very complex as in the processing logic does not involve any database connections or XML parsing or humongous processing tasks like that just the implementation of a basic neural network that is it. But it is going to be used by a large community. In general I wanted to know what to use for using neural network for web development!